# how to pass data from View to Controller using ajax get or post in mvc with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, parameter-passing, viewbag, asp.net-mvc-views

I am trying to pass data from View to Controller Action Method using ajax as follows:-

I have Membership instance of user which I passed in from another controller to this view below using viewbag somewhat like this ViewBag.MyUser = MyUser;

Now I want to pass 'MyUser' to another Controller form this view using ajax as below.

```
 $('#Link').click(function () {      
        $.ajax({
            url: http://localhost/Account/Process,
            type: 'POST',
            data: '@ViewBag.MyUser',
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function () {                
            }
        });
```

The ActionMethod to which I am posting is as follows

```
public ActionResult Process(MembershipUser MyUser)
{
   //Do somethihng with MyUser
}
```

If I pass do ajax post, I get error internally at  `BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)` stating that 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.' and control does not even comes to my actionmethod.

If I remove the parameter `(MembershipUser MyUser)` from Action Method it posts to Action method, but then

1. how can i pass 'MyUser' in such case without parameter from that view to controller ?
2. is there something wrong with routes ? if yes what should be the route ?
3. or should i use get or post ?
4. Where should i cast the MyUser back to MembershipUser ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you can't pass *MyUser* as parameter from JQuery because JQuery doesn't know the class *MembershipUser*. Remember that JQuery is a client side language and *MembershipUser* is defined in C# on the server side.

You could pass the properties that you need from the *MyUser* object to the *Process* action using *GET* as follows (supossing that the *MyUser* object has and *ID* an a *Name*):

```
$('#Link').click(function () {      
    $.ajax({
        url: http://localhost/Account/Process,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 
                id: "@ViewBag.MyUser.ID",
                name: "@ViewBag.MyUser.Name" 
              },
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function () {                
        }
    });
```

The action should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Process(int id, string name)
{
   //Do something
}
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks!! that helped.But I am still not sure why we cannot send "MembershipUser" as an object and cast it back in action method.

Comment: This is because you cannot pass "object" type data through ajax. It has to be a string...