# How to pass values - controller to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC and want to pass values, controller to controller

My code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<string> SportsName = new List<string>();
    var sport = Db.Universities.Where(ud => ud.Contact.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Trim()).SingleOrDefault();
    var spt = Db.Departments.Where(i => i.UniversityID == sport.UniversityID && i.DepartmentCodeID == 4).SingleOrDefault();
    unvId = int.Parse(sport.UniversityID.ToString());
    List<Sport> dept = Db.Sports.Where(s => s.DepartmentID == spt.DepartmentID).ToList();

    foreach (var sname in dept.ToList())
    {
        var name = Db.SportsCodes.Where(s => s.SportsCodeID == sname.SportsCodeID).First();
        SportsName.Add(name.SportsName);
    }
    ViewBag.SportsName = SportsName;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create(string sports)
{
    ViewBag.SportsName = sports;
    int s = unvId;
    return View();
}
```

I want the 'sport' value in create action also. How to get the value of 'sport' in create action?

Answer (score 0):

What I guess from your question is You want to pass the SportsName from Index to Create.

From Index View (.cshtml) when you call the **Create** method through AJAX call, pass the value of the **ViewBag.Sports** as a parameter.

**For Example :**

```
$('#Link').click(function () {      
    $.ajax({
        url: http://localhost/Sports/Create,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 
                sports: "@ViewBag.SportsName" 
              },
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function () {                
        }
    });
```

[**Note :** Here it is considered that name of your controller is Sports]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931641/how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller-using-ajax-get-or-post-in-mvc-with-para) answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options.  If only individual action methods need that value, fetch the value in each action method that needs it:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    var sport = Db.Universities.Where(ud => ud.Contact.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Trim()).SingleOrDefault();
    // ...
}
```

If the repeated code seems unsightly, abstract it to a helper method:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    var sport = GetSport();
    // ...
}

private SomeType GetSport()
{
    return Db.Universities.Where(ud => ud.Contact.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Trim()).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

If it should be accessible anywhere in the class and is logically a class-level member, make it a class-level member:

```
private SomeType sport = Db.Universities.Where(ud => ud.Contact.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Trim()).SingleOrDefault();

public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    // sport is accessible here
    // ...
}
```

Though now that I notice it, this begs the question "What is `Db`"?  If that's a database context then it looks like you've expanded the scope of it beyond what it really *should* be.  Database contexts and connections should be kept in as small a scope as possible.  Each method that needs one should create it, use it, and destroy it.  Sharing them at a larger scope without explicitly knowing what you're doing is inviting a whole host of problems.  In this case, the class-level member would be initialized in the constructor:

```
private SomeType sport;

public YourController()
{
    using (var Db = BuildYourDBContext())
        sport = Db.Universities.Where(ud => ud.Contact.UserName.ToLower().Trim() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Trim()).SingleOrDefault();
}

public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    // sport is accessible here
    // ...
}
```

Any way you look at it, the point is that being a *controller* doesn't really make a difference.  The controller is an object like any object in an object-oriented system.  It shares members exactly the same way.